# p-value of 4 observations in 5 trials with one-sided hypothesis p<=0.8

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

This should be trivial. But when I evaluate the p-value for 4 observations in 5 binomial trials for a one sided test/hypothesis H0: p<=0.8, H_a: p>0.8

In scipy notation:

```
stats.binom_test(x=4, n=5, p=0.8, alternative='greater')
```

I get p-value = 0.73. I would have assumed that under H0, with 4 observations the largest p in the hypothesized range i.e. p=0.8 is the relevant one.

Furthermore, at p=0.8 for 5 trials, the outcome of 4 observations is the most likely one. Hence, the p-value should be 1, shouldn't it? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Could you explain why "p=0.8 is the relevant one" might depend on how many successes appeared in the five trials?  One concern is whether your $H_0$ was developed *as a response* to observing $0.8=4/5$ successes or whether it was formulated independently of the data.  The former produces a meaningless test.

Comment: Your second issue first: 0.8 is not related with the observation. It is fixed "externally". First issue: I understand the $H_0: p\leq0.8$ as follows: Within all $p$ allowed by the hypothesis, the relevant p-value for the observation  ist the largest one. This I thought I find it with $p=0.8$, as 4 is the most likely observation in 5 trials with $p=0.8$ and hence the p-value should be 1?

Comment: The p-value will be computed as the chance (according to $H_0$) of observing either a $4$ or a $5.$  If that's not clear, then please consult our threads on p-values, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31.

Comment: I probably don't follow the question, but if you conduct a two-sided test, the p-value will be 1. If you sum the p-value from the 'greater' test and 1 - the p-value of the 'less' test, the result will be approximately 1. (Assuming x/n=p in the test).